# What is the connector shown in the photo?

Tags: connector, standard

Is the connector marked as CN3 in this photo a standard one? If so what is it called? [image: pcb]

Comment: Looks like the M.2 Edge Connector such as this: http://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/m-2-connectors/Y30no.html

Note that there are multiple "keying" options for this connector (the location of gap in the pins).

Comment: @Mike I suspected M.2 initially but the left section has 5 pins in that one, if at all present (depends on the keying).

Comment: If I counted correctly the left section has 12 pins - which matches M.2 Key E.

Comment: <Quints eyes> OH! There's CN3... why couldn't you describe a location for something that was easier to see lol? It took me a little while to find where you were talking about. But yes, Mike is correct.

Comment: @Mike Indeed, thanks a lot! Sorry, I had to spend more time on your first comment before rejecting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After counting 12 pins before the seperator, it looks like this is an M.2 Key E connector.

[image]

Such as [this one](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2199125-4.html?q=&d=125684&type=products&samples=N) from TE Connectivity.